# populating select dropdowns dependent on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm nearly finished with my small task of populating select dropdowns then outputting a relevant number. The select a company etc works.

Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3MK3D/1/

I need to now generate the appropriate companies in the select dropdown dependent on which **sector** is selected. I've created a new javascript array for personal companies.

I've thought of maybe doing something like this and passing the correct variable to the appropriate function but not really sure how to implement it:

```
var companiesArray;

    $('#sector').on('change', function(e){
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var sectorSelected = this.value;
        if( sectorSelected == 'business' ) {
            companiesArray = 'insurancecompanies';

        } else if( sectorSelected == 'personal' ) {
            companiesArray = 'personalcompanies';

        } else {

        }
    });
```

There is probably a better way?

Comment: roughly how many sectors are you dealing with? And will their likely be a lot of cross referencing of companies between sectors

Comment: Just two, business and personal

Comment: Nope, if one or the other is selected then the array changes for the functions below.

Comment: Makes it pretty simple...add a property to the object you have that classifies it....could be text...business/personal or numeric..just realized you already have arrays...how you split it up isn't critical. Not a complicated relationship when only 2 sectors

Comment: Are you wanting `<optgroup>` subheadings?Sounds like may have numerous business catgories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `companies` object that has your `sector` select values as keys to the relevant arrays:

```
var companies = {
    business : [
        { 
            name : 'Advent', 
            property : '01242 674 674', 
            fleet : '', 
            motortrade : ''
        },
        {   
            name : 'Allianz', 
            property : '0844 412 9988', 
            fleet : '0800 587 5858', 
            motortrade : '' 
        },
        // other insurance companies
    ],
    personal : [
        // personal companies
    ]
}
```

Then:

```
$('#sector').on('change', function(e){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var sectorSelected = this.value;
    var companyArray = companies[sectorSelected];
    // iterate over companyArray and create the relevant option objects for #company
});
```

Comment: Any change you could update my existing jsfiddle with this? http://jsfiddle.net/3MK3D/1/

Comment: @RobMorris There are other parts of your code that will need updating to reflect the changes, but: http://jsfiddle.net/3MK3D/2/

Comment: Ah yes, Now i have to generate insurance type select dependent on the company choice like it was doing. I see you have commented that out. I need to somehow get the sectorSelected and pass it to the findCompany array?

Comment: @RobMorris The commented out part is partly because it needs changing and partly because it didn't make much sense to me to pre-populate the company list before a sector had been chosen.

Comment: No I understand now thanks. My question is how do I pass the chosen sector variable to the findCompany function?

Comment: Made some changes to save references to the jQuery objects selecting the dropdowns: http://jsfiddle.net/3MK3D/4/ Added a `sector` parameter to the `findCompany` function, then called it like this: `findCompany($sector.val, valueSelected)`.